# Draw Box works but Line does not

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I create a project.When I press "New Box" I want to create a blue box.Then when I press 'Line' I want to draw a line and connect the lines and the box. I created box's codes and this is working but line's codes is not working. Actually line's codes is working another window/folder but not here working. Maybe I made a mistake when write a codes.

This Window and main codes..

```
public class Cerceve extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
    JPanel MAINPANEL, LEFTPANEL, RIGHTPANEL;
    JButton btnBox, btnClear;
    DragListener drag = new DragListener();
    JButton btnLine;

    public Cerceve() {
        // ÇERÇEVE OLUŞTUR
        super("ÇİZGE PROGRAMI");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(1200, 700);
        setResizable(false);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);

        // ÜZERİNE BİLEŞENLERİ EKLE
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        MAINPANEL = new JPanel();
        MAINPANEL.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        this.add(MAINPANEL, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        MAINPANEL.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        LEFTPANEL = new JPanel();
        LEFTPANEL.setBackground(Color.GRAY);
        MAINPANEL.add(LEFTPANEL, BorderLayout.WEST);

        RIGHTPANEL = new JPanel();
        RIGHTPANEL.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        MAINPANEL.add(RIGHTPANEL, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        btnBox = new JButton("New Box");
        LEFTPANEL.add(btnBox);

        btnClear = new JButton("Clear");
        LEFTPANEL.add(btnClear);

        btnLine = new JButton("Line");
        LEFTPANEL.add(btnLine);

        btnBox.addActionListener(this);
        btnClear.addActionListener(this);
        btnLine.addActionListener(this);

       }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
           if (e.getSource() == btnBox) {
               Box box = new Box();
               RIGHTPANEL.add(box);
               RIGHTPANEL.repaint();
               box.addMouseMotionListener(drag);
               box.addMouseListener(drag);
          }

           else if (e.getSource() == btnClear) {
               RIGHTPANEL.removeAll();
               RIGHTPANEL.repaint();
       }

           else if (e.getSource() == btnLine) {
               Line line = new Line();
               RIGHTPANEL.repaint();
               RIGHTPANEL.add(line);
               line.addMouseListener(line.mouseHandler);
               line.addMouseMotionListener(line.mouseMotionListener);

        }
    }
}
```

THİS İS BOX PACKAGE

```
    public class Box extends JPanel {
    public Box() {
        setLayout(null);
        setBackground(Color.BLUE);
        setSize(50, 50);
        setLocation(0, 0);
    }

}
```

THİS İS DRAG LİSTENER PACKAGE

```
    class DragListener extends MouseInputAdapter {
    Point location;
    MouseEvent mouseInfo;

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent me) {
        mouseInfo = me;
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent me) {
        if (SwingUtilities.isLeftMouseButton(me) == true) {
            Component component = me.getComponent();
            location = component.getLocation(location);
            int x = location.x - mouseInfo.getX() + me.getX();
            int y = location.y - mouseInfo.getY() + me.getY();
            component.setLocation(x, y);
        }
    }
}
```

**THİS İS LİNE PACKAGE**

```
    public class Line extends JFrame {
    private int xBegin = 0;
    private int xEnd = 0;
    private int yBegin = 0;
    private int yEnd = 0;

    public MouseListener mouseHandler = new MouseAdapter() {

        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            xBegin = e.getX();
            yBegin = e.getY();
            repaint();
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
            xEnd = e.getX();
            yEnd = e.getY();
            repaint();
        }
    };

    public MouseMotionListener mouseMotionListener = new MouseMotionAdapter() {

        @Override
        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
            xEnd = e.getX();
            yEnd = e.getY();
            repaint();
        }
    };

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        super.paint(g);
        g.drawLine(xBegin, yBegin, xEnd, yEnd);

    }

}
```

[image]

Comment: You might want to take a look at this: https://sourceforge.net/p/tus/code/HEAD/tree/tjacobs/ui/shape/

Comment: You should not be subclassing  JFrame.  Why not just use the `java.awt.geom` classes that have your shapes already defined with some very useful methods?